# Selenium won't Start headless on remote server

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, mozilla

I try to automate a routine task on web with Selenium on remote Server.

So when I try to start webdriver in python it fails with `connection refused` error:

```
instance-1@instance-1:~$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
>>> options = Options()
>>> options.headless = True
>>> options.log.level = "trace"
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options )


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/instance1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/instance-1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/instance-1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/instance-1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/instance-1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: connection refused
```

I use Python 2.7 and Firefox, detailed versions are below.

```
instance-1@instance-1:~$ 
instance-1@instance-1:~$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
instance-1@instance-1:~$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 75.0
instance-1@instance-1:~$ python -c "import selenium; print(selenium.__version__)"
3.141.0
instance-1@instance-1:~$ geckodriver --version 
geckodriver 0.26.0 (e9783a644016 2019-10-10 13:38 +0000)

The source code of this program is available from
testing/geckodriver in https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central.

This program is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0.
You can obtain a copy of the license at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
instance-1@instance-1:~$ which geckodriver 
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver
instance-1@instance-1:~$
```

Also, I've setted virtual display via Xvbf like this

```
instance-1@instance-1:~$ Xvfb :99 -ac &
[1] 16171
instance-1@instance-1:~$ export DISPLAY=:99
```

My geckotrace output is

```
1588545824498   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileOn8vbe"
1588545824519   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1:44835
*** You are running in headless mode.
1588545828833   addons.webextension.doh-rollout@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'doh-rollout@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: networkStatus
1588545829585   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1588545829585   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1588545829585   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1588545829585   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
1588545830466   Marionette      TRACE   Marionette enabled
1588545831067   Marionette      TRACE   Received observer notification toplevel-window-ready
1588545884800   mozrunner::runner       DEBUG   Killing process 16183
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
1588545885811   webdriver::server       DEBUG   <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"timeout","message":"connection refused","stacktrace":""}}
```

Should I specify something else?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error, Connection Refused. Are you using a proxy or sth?

Comment: Nope, I don't. I run on remote server and but not use proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem like this:

- Reboot node in order to drop all settings made and processes locked
- Use `xvfbwrapper` instead of running headless Firefox
- Be sure to close driver and virtual display

Code example

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
from selenium import webdriver
vdisplay = Xvfb()
vdisplay.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.quit()
vdisplay.stop()
```